# How to connect from Laravel to images located higher than Laravel root directory?

Tags: laravel

My linux server conains 2 directory:

**home/username/www/**- is root directory for Laravel

**home/username/zimages/** -is directory for upload images (assume that this directory could be anywhere on the server).

I need to access from Laravel to these images.

I created symlink:

```
ln -s /home/username/zimages /home/username/www/public
```

and command

```
ls /home/username/www/public/zimages/1693240044.jpg
```

returns this file successfully.

But https://xxx.biz/zimages/1693240044.jpg returns 404.

What do I need to do?

Comment: Which webserver is this?

Comment: It is Apache web server

Comment: You need to enable apache to follow symlinks in your host configuration (if you haven't already). See [this](https://superuser.com/questions/244245/how-do-i-get-apache-to-follow-symlinks) for more details